# Attempted php hack/inject in search AND user-agent: "print(238947899389478923-34567343546345)"

Tags: php, wordpress, sql-injection

Viewing my latest search queries I stumbled upon the below query.

```
d3d3lmfrdglllxnryxquzgsv"{${pr.i.nt(238947899389478923-34567343546345)}}"
```

**Please note:** I've inserted the dots in `print` just to make sure that there's nothing evaluated in here for some reason, as I have no clue about the functioning of this query.

The query has been made in several different formats:

```
d3d3lmfrdglllxnryxquzgsv");pr.i.nt(238947899389478923-34567343546345);//

d3d3lmfrdglllxnryxquzgsv}print(238947899389478923-34567343546345);{
```

As the above suggests there might be more code involved which sadly aren't available for me to view at this time.

Doing a google search for the `pr.i.nt(238947899389478923-34567343546345)` part gives a list of apparently hacked websites and a single [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/hacking/comments/a4zcl3/interesting_search_term_attempted_hack/) regarding this issue with only a single comment.

Am I supposed to be worried about this, and what is the functioning of such query?

Some background info:

- I'm using Wordpress, latest version
- Using ajax-search with a combination of the Relevanssi and SearchWP Live Ajax Search plugins - both on latest version.
- Wordfence security plugin is activated and updated.
- PHP version 7.1
- jQuery activated

**UPDATE:** I've also just found the same string in the person's/bot's user-agent stating the following:

```
aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYWt0aWUtc2thdC5kay8{${pr.i.nt(238947899389478923-34567343546345)}}
```

Comment: Check these, in general: https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked and https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress

Comment: And https://managewp.com/blog/sql-injection-hack-wordpress-security

Comment: @jasie thank you, but I'm currently not even sure whether it has had any effect - doing the search query my self doesn't result in any visible or notable results.